# Перемещение локальной переменной типа абстрактного класса из виртуального метода

Tags: c++, наследование, полиморфизм, неопределённое-поведение, raii

Требуется реализовать более одного класса с перегрузками арифметических операторов, чтобы с ними можно было работать через указатель/ссылку на абстрактный класс от которого они наследованы. Обычно бинарные арифметические операторы такие как +, -, *, /, % возвращают копию объекта, сконструированную и изменённую внутри перегрузки оператора, таким образом в простейшем случае сигнатура перегрузки любого такого оператора для класса `A` выглядит следующим образом: `A operator+(int v) { A tmp(*this); tmp.v += v; return tmp; }`.

В качеств примера есть следующий код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Abstract class
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual Base&& operator+(int) = 0;
    virtual Base& operator+=(int) = 0;
};

// Implementation
struct Derived : public Base {
    int a = 0;
    Derived() { std::cout << "<default ctor>\n"; }
    Derived(Derived&& other) {std::cout << "<move d ctor " << other.a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = other.a; }
    Derived(Derived& other) {std::cout << "<copy d ctor " << other.a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = other.a; }
    Derived(Base&& other) {std::cout << "<move b ctor " << dynamic_cast<Derived&&>(other).a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = dynamic_cast<Derived&&>(other).a; }
    Derived(Base& other) {std::cout << "<copy b ctor " << dynamic_cast<Derived&>(other).a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(other).a; }
    virtual ~Derived() {std::cout << "<dctor of " << a << ">\n";}

    virtual Derived&& operator+(int v) override {
        std::cout << "<+ from " << a << ' ';
        Derived tmp(*this);
        tmp.a += v;
        std::cout << " to " << tmp.a << ">\n";
        return std::move(tmp);
    }

    virtual Derived& operator+=(int v) override {
        std::cout << "<+= from " << a << ' ';
        a += v;
        std::cout << " to " << a << ">\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* a = new Derived();            // <default ctor>
    *a += 5;                            // <+= from 0 to 5>    
    Base* b = new Derived(*a + 10);     // <+ from 5 <copy d ctor 5 to 0> to 15> <dctor of 15> <move b ctor 15 to 0>
                                        // (ERROR: dctor of tmp before move ctor to outer var!!!)
    std::cout
        << "a = " << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(a)->a
        << "; b = " << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)->a
        << '\n';                        // a = 5; b = 15
    
    delete a;                           // <dctor of 5>
    delete b;                           // <dctor of 15>
    return 0;
}
```

**Проблема 1:** если мы напишем `virual Base operator+(int) = 0;` компилятор/статический анализатор закономерно ругаются, мол нельзя возвращать абстрактный класс по значению, что в принципе логично, как следствие меняем возврат по значение `Base` на возврат по rvalue-ссылке `Base&&`, что казалось бы должно помочь, но...

**Проблема 2:** компиляторы очень интересным образом обрабатывают явно указанный возврат по rvalue-ссылке из методов. Обращаю внимание на 3-ю строку функции `main`. Ситуация следующая:

- Запускается метод `Base&& Base::operator+(int)` -> `Derived&& Derived::operator+(int)`

  - Конструируется объект класса `Derived` с именем `tmp` через конструктор копирования от `*this` на стэке
  - `tmp` изменяется (`tmp.a += v`)
  - `tmp` деконструируется
- Внешний объект конструируется через конструктор перемещения от `tmp` ***который уже уничтожен***

Таким образом мы получаем UB, когда объект конструируется от куска неинициализированной памяти, да ещё и с освобождённой части стэка.

Если кто знает - возможно ли это как-либо сделать без UB?

Comment: *"компиляторы очень интересным образом обрабатывают явно указанный возврат по rvalue-ссылке из методов"* - проблема тут не в rvalue-ссылке, а в том, что это ссылка на локальную переменную!

Comment: Копирующие конструкторы обычно должны принимать `const T &`, не `T &`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы забыли про управление памятью.

Рассмотрим ваш оператор `virtual Base?? operator+(int) = 0;` подробнее, с позиции "что он вообще должен вернуть". А вернуть-то он обязан **новый объект**! Но если объект новый, и к тому же неизвестного размера (virtual же!) - кто-то должен выделить для него память, а потом освободить её.

Для управления памятью в С++ принята идиома RAII в общем и умные указатели в частности. К примеру, тут подойдёт `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> operator+(int) =0;
    virtual Base& operator+=(int) =0;
};
```

Однако, хоть такой вариант и будет работать - он странный. В нём результат операции сложения невозможно снова сложить, вместо условного `x + 5 + 6` придётся писать `*(x+5) + 6`.

Это связано с более фундаментальной ошибкой - смешиванием механизмов, предназначенных для работы с объектами как значениями (операторы) и для работы с объектами как ссылками (полиморфизм).

Решение? Нужно разделить эти объекты! Пусть один класс отвечает за полиморфизм, а второй - за перегрузку операторов.

Например, вот так:

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Clone() =0;
    virtual void Add(int) =0;
}

class base_ptr {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr; // или shared_ptr
public:
    explicit base_ptr(std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

    // …

    base_ptr& operator += (int arg) {
        ptr->Add(arg);
        return *this;
    }

    base_ptr operator + (int arg) {
        auto clone = ptr->Clone();
        clone->Add(arg);
        return base_ptr(std::move(clone));
    }

    base_ptr operator + (int arg) && {
        ptr->Add(arg);
        return base_ptr(std::move(ptr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Виртуальный объект по значению возвращать не получится. Можно только ссылкой на выделенную память. Сделал класс `BaseTemp` указателей на временный объект, который автоматически удаляется.
*Как аналог std::unique_ptr<Base>*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base ;

struct BaseTemp {
  Base * p ;
  BaseTemp(Base*x):p{x}{}
  ~BaseTemp();
} ;

// Abstract class
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual BaseTemp operator+(int)=0;
    virtual Base& operator+=(int) = 0;
};

BaseTemp::~BaseTemp(){
  std::cout << "<BaseTemp dctor " << p << ">\n";
  delete p;
}

// Implementation
struct Derived : public Base {
    int a = 0;
    Derived() { std::cout << "<default ctor>\n"; }
    Derived(BaseTemp bt):a{static_cast<Derived*>(bt.p)->a} { std::cout << "<BaseTemp ctor>\n"; }
    Derived(Derived&& other) {std::cout << "<move d ctor " << other.a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = other.a; }
    Derived(Derived& other) {std::cout << "<copy d ctor " << other.a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = other.a; }
    Derived(Base&& other) {std::cout << "<move b ctor " << dynamic_cast<Derived&&>(other).a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = dynamic_cast<Derived&&>(other).a; }
    Derived(Base& other) {std::cout << "<copy b ctor " << dynamic_cast<Derived&>(other).a << " to " << a << ">\n"; a = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(other).a; }
    virtual ~Derived() {std::cout << "<dctor of " << a << ">\n";}

    virtual BaseTemp operator+(int v) {
        std::cout << "<+ from " << a << ' ';
        Derived * tmpp = new Derived(*this) ;
        tmpp->a += v;
        std::cout << " to " << tmpp->a << ">\n";
        return tmpp;
    }

    virtual Derived& operator+=(int v) override {
        std::cout << "<+= from " << a << ' ';
        a += v;
        std::cout << " to " << a << ">\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* a = new Derived();            // <default ctor>
    (*a) += 5;                            // <+= from 0 to 5>    
    Base* b = new Derived((*a) + 10);     // <+ from 5 <copy d ctor 5 to 0> to 15> <dctor of 15> <move b ctor 15 to 0>
                                        // (ERROR: dctor of tmp before move ctor to outer var!!!)
    std::cout
        << "a = " << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(a)->a
        << "; b = " << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b)->a
        << '\n';                        // a = 5; b = 15
    
    delete a;                           // <dctor of 5>
    delete b;                           // <dctor of 15>
    return 0;
}
```

*Пока вроде пашет. Проверьте сами..*

Comment: В принципе хорошее решение, для этого вполне можно использовать ```std::unique_ptr<Base>```. Хотелось бы лишний раз не выделять память в куче, в принципе для этого можно внутри ```BaseTmp``` хранить union с дочерними классами наследованными от абстрактного класса ```Base```, реализация в принципе не сильно поменяется. Спасибо за идею)

Comment: @ByteGear Лучше уж `std::variant` вместо union-а.